# What is the diffrence between the two paypal payment pages?

Tags: paypal, payment

When trying to pay for products/services through paypal, I get to see two possible options. One of them allows you to pay through your paypal account or debit/credit card while the other option only allows to pay through your paypal or register a new account.

I have trie to go over all the information about business accounts on paypal, but did not find any related information.

I am attaching screenshots of both paymnet sites.

Any guidance is vey much appreciated.

[image: First option] [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called `Account optional` in PayPal.This is a merchant/seller setting and **no buyer** has control over it.

To turn the feature on or off, simply log in to PayPal, go to Profile, click ‘Website Payment Preferences’ under the Selling Preferences column and tick the yes/no box under PayPal Account Optional.

If this feature is turned `On`, then you will get to see `Pay with Credit/Debit Card`,

if not you will see `Create a PayPal account`.

**P.S** But, sometimes, even if this feature is `on`, PayPal will still display "Create a PayPal account".
This is due to some restrictions (buyers country,IP, how many times guest checkout is used etc). Its a complex limitation.